# how to create subset of large file with echo tail

Tags: sed, command-line-interface, large-files, tail, logfile

I want to open a large error log file (with millions of lines). 
To investigate, I just need to look at the recent log. So I would like to copy the "tail" result of the large file to a new file. 
How to get it?

```
echo "tail largefile.log" > lastline.txt
```

Something like this. But I need the output of

```
tail largefile.log
```

to be inside lastline.txt 
This can also be achieved using "sed" command, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```sh
tail -n 1 largefile.log > lastline.txt
```

Use the `-n` parameter to specify how many lines you want.

From the [tail man pages:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

> ```
> -n, --lines=[+]NUM
>               output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n
>               +NUM to output starting with line NUM
> ```

Comment: Thanks for help. That's what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @Sintara Glad to hear it helped. You can always accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)